# activate virtualenv in git bash using pycharm on windows

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, virtualenv

I have activated `git bash` instead of `command prompt` (cmd) in Pycharm. Whenever I try to activate the virtualenv, which is named `venv`, I face with two problems:

1. After I execute `source venv/Scripts/activate`, face with the following error:

```
bash: basename: command not found
()
```

which (I think) means that it doesn't recognize `source` command.

2. Running `./venv/Scripts/activate` has also another problem:

```
You must source this script: $ source ./venv/Scripts/activate
()
```

What should I do?

[image: pycharm terminal]

**PS:** Also `<exact-directory>/venv/Scripts/activate` works properly in cmd.

Comment: Try to `source venv/bin/activate`.

Comment: @DinkoPehar As I have mentioned in the post, it doesn't work.

Comment: I wrote `bin` directory, not `Scripts` directory. Additional, do you have `activate.sh` in `Scripts` directory ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar I know but I have tried the both ways. They didn't work properly.  No there isn't any  file with `.sh`  format in the directory. I just activate, activate.bat, activate.ps1 and activate.xsh.

Comment: Did you create your *virtualenv* using cmd ? Try creating it using `git bash` then `source your_env/bin/activate` ...

Comment: @ِDinkoPehar No I didn't. I have create everything through bash

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: It's not mentioned in the original post but I would think the venv has been created with Pycharm. In Pycharm the option under `File > Settings > Terminal > "Activate virtualenv"` if this is checked it will activate venv automatically when you open the pycharm terminal but it will not show the mention `venv` in the terminal. Confirm this with `wich python`. If you uncheck it you will be able to activate it yourself (and will see the `venv` mention) using `source venv/Scripts/activate` and deactivate it after with `deactivate`. Note there is no `venv/bin/` on widows (at least in my experience).

Comment: @Touten I was having the same problem the question mentions and your approach did work for me, the checkbox was making the bash use the default python and it was trouble to set the environment. Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a python package called `pipenv`.

It can be installed easily by entering `pip install pipenv` command. Then start using it by executing the following command:

```
pipenv shell
```

It automatically creates a new virtual environment.

Freezing the packages is as simple as:

```
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 21):

There is a setting in File > Settings > Terminal for "Activate virtualenv". This works for cmd shell, but seems not to work with bash in Windows 10. If I uncheck that setting, 'source venv/Scripts/activate' activates as expected.

Comment: If it doesn't work try opening a new terminal after making the change in settings

Comment: Had an issue where I could activate environment, but all bash commands weren't recognized anymore. This solution fixed that.

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer appears to be in the comment added by @Touten.

This is actually just a display issue -  the venv is activated, but it doesn't display the usual (venv) tag in the terminal. This can be confirmed by calling `which python` and seeing that is displays the venv's python.

Alternatively, you can follow the answer by @Nikki-Aaron to disable automatically activating the venv. Then you can activate it using `source venv/Scripts/activate` and it will show the tag in the terminal.

Comment: I can't test it now but for appreciating your answer I give upvote to you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

just write this command line in your virtual environment file:

```
. Scripts/activate
```